How to Disable Trackpoint in wayland?
I need to disable the trackpoint located in the middle of the keyboard It's quite annoying because it's very sensitive; even if I tap on other keys, the cursor moves. I'm using a Dell Latitude E7440. I am using wayland

I try to disable in BIOS and Xinputand i also pull off the round cap but nothing worked (but i think that xinput cmd will not work in wayland) and i don't want to disable this key by opening the keybord and disable this key physically.
I am new in fedora sorry for my bad english and dirty keybord (this is old image of my pc i cleaned my keybord)
